# Error: Cannot find control and Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

How to make a checkbox assigned to one row? Currently, the checkbox works on all rows. I would like it to be assigned to the index as well as the delete button. How to do it?

Btw, does someone know why this error in the browser console?

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null

My ts file:

```
export class RowComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() rowForm: FormGroup;
  subscription: Subscription;
  showInput = false;


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private parentControl: ControlContainer) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.rowForm.addControl("rows",this.formBuilder.array([this.createRow(true)]))

    });
    const checkbox2 = <FormControl>this.rowForm.get('checkbox2');
    const input3 = <FormControl>this.rowForm.get('input3');

    this.subscription = checkbox2.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        input3.setValidators([Validators.required, ])
      }
      else {
        input3.setValidators(null);
      }

      input3.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  createRow(disabled:boolean=false): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      input1: [{value:'',disabled:disabled}, Validators.required],
      input2: [{value:'',disabled:disabled}, Validators.required],
      input3: [{value:'',disabled:disabled}],
      checkbox2: [{value:'',disabled:disabled}],
    });
  }

  toggleInput(index: number) {
    this.showInput = !this.showInput;
  }

  get formArray() {
    return this.rowForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
  }

  addNewRow() {
    this.formArray.push(this.createRow());
  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    this.formArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  getControls() {
    return (this.rowForm.get('rows') as FormArray).controls;
  }
}
```

My html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="rowForm">
  <div *ngIf="rowForm.get('rows')" formArrayName="rows">
    <div *ngFor="let rows of getControls(); let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i">

      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" formControlName="checkbox2"  name="checkbox2" (click)="toggleInput(i)">Show hidden option!</mat-checkbox>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Input1" formControlName="input1"  name="input1" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Input2" formControlName="input2"  name="input2" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field *ngIf="showInput"  class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Input3" formControlName="input3"  name="input3" required>
        <mat-error>Title is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <button mat-button color="primary" *ngIf="getControls().length > 1" (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addNewRow()" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Row</button><br>
  
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't put `this.rowForm.addControl("rows",this.formBuilder.array([this.createRow(true)]))` it inside `setTimeout`. You're trying to subscribe the checkbox valuechanges before assigning the new control.

Comment: Where should I put it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make a checkbox assigned to one row? Currently, the checkbox works on all rows. I would like it to be assigned to the index as well as the delete button. How to do it?

To handle every row independently, you could create an object instead:

```
export class RowComponent implements OnInit {
  readonly inputVisibleMapper: Record<number, boolean> = {}

  // ...

  toggleInput(index: number) {
    this.inputVisibleMapper[index] = !this.inputVisibleMapper[index];
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="inputVisibleMapper[i]" class="example-full-width">
  ...
</mat-form-field>
```

---

> Btw, does someone know why this error in the browser console?

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null

Because you're trying to get a `FormControl` that resides inside an `array` (more specifically a `FormArray`) without specify which index do you want query (also the `setTimeout` could be problematic).

It appears that you want to listen when `checkbox2` changes to set/remove validators from `input3` control. If so, you can do this in `toggleInput()`:

```
toggleInput(index: number) {
  this.inputVisibleMapper[index] = !this.inputVisibleMapper[index];
  const formGroup = this.rowForm.get(`rows.${index}`) as FormGroup;
  const checkbox2 = formGroup.get('checkbox2');
  const input3 = formGroup.get('input3');

  if (checkbox2.value) {
    input3.setValidators(Validators.required)
  } else {
    // Note that I replaced `setValidators(null)` as there's a dedicated method for it: `clearValidators()`
    input3.clearValidators();
  }

  input3.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

---

Also, note that you could replace the 3 method calls in template just by storing the `FormArray` in a class property, and thus avoiding unnecessary calls.

**Full version**:

**TS**:

```
export class RowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() rowForm: FormGroup;
  readonly inputVisibleMapper: Record<number, boolean> = {};
  formArray: FormArray;

  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formArray = this.formBuilder.array([this.createRow(true)]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.rowForm.addControl('rows', this.formArray);
    });
  }

  createRow(disabled = false): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      input1: [{ value: '', disabled }, Validators.required],
      input2: [{ value: '', disabled }, Validators.required],
      input3: [{ value: '', disabled }],
      checkbox2: [{ value: '', disabled }],
    });
  }

  toggleInput(index: number) {
    this.inputVisibleMapper[index] = !this.inputVisibleMapper[index];
    const formGroup = this.formArray.at(index) as FormGroup;
    const checkbox2 = formGroup.get('checkbox2');
    const input3 = formGroup.get('input3');

    if (checkbox2.value) {
      input3.setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else {
      // Note that I replaced `setValidators(null)` as there's a dedicated method for it: `clearValidators()`
      input3.clearValidators();
    }

    input3.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  addNewRow() {
    this.formArray.push(this.createRow());
  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    this.formArray.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<form [formGroup]="rowForm">
  <div *ngIf="formArray" formArrayName="rows">
    <div *ngFor="let rows of formArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">

      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" formControlName="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" (click)="toggleInput(i)">Show hidden option!</mat-checkbox>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Input1" formControlName="input1" name="input1" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Input2" formControlName="input2" name="input2" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field *ngIf="inputVisibleMapper[i]" class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Input3" formControlName="input3" name="input3" required>
        <mat-error>Title is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <button mat-button color="primary" *ngIf="formArray.length > 1" (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addNewRow()" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Row</button><br>
  
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghp9px)

Comment: thanks it's working but  I've got a new error "core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'rows'" and "core.js:6210 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.."

Comment: + after checking the box and unchecking input3 is required (it shouldn't be cause it's hidden)

Comment: Well, the first and second error could be, as I said, because of the `setTimeout`. I didn't understand what you mean by *after checking the box and unchecking input3 is required (it shouldn't be cause it's hidden)*...

Comment: Cause it's like when the box is check the input3 show up and it's required, but after you uncheck the checkbox (it's not check) the input is still required but hidden, do you think it might also be cause of settimeout?

Comment: I haven't made this setTimeout, some from stackoverflow told me to add this. Can I just delete it? Or should I put this somewhere else?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a demo without `setTimeout`. Please, take a look... Well, probably the checkbox isn't behaving correctly because you're using `(click)` instead of `(change)`. Also, why are you trying to click on a **disabled** checkbox and expecting it to be checked?